# Jquery keeping score and progressing through "levels"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a simple game where you click a moving image and gain points every time you click. I have the score sort of working where when the user clicks, the score will go up. I am wondering what to write so that when the user reaches score of "100" they can move on to the next level, where the image will speed up. Or maybe as a starting point, at least having the function recognize that the user has reached 100 points.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#cursor').animate({
    top: '500px'
    , left: '500px'
});
$('img').click(function () {
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    $('#score').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 10;

       function levelup() {
            if (("#score") >= 10) {
                alert('Level Up');
            }
        }
    });
    $(this).animate({
        top: (Math.random() * window.innerHeight - this.height) + 'px'
        , left: (Math.random() * window.innerWidth - this.width) + 'px'
    })
})

function explode() {
    alert("TIME UP!");
}
setTimeout(explode, 30000);
```

});

This is what I have so far, this recognized when the user clicks and gives 10 points per click. I can not figure out how to get that score to talk back to the javascript file to progress the game.
Thanks.

EDIT: 
    '

```
<head>
    <title>jQuery animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>   
    <img id="cursor" src="cursor.png" width="100"> 
    <div id="score">0</div>
</body>

</html>'
```

I feel like there is some confusion in my question. I just want to get the game to recognize the user has reached 100 points.

Comment: Could you possibly include the JavaScript file? It would be helpful if we could check how the file progresses the game and how it is structured.

Comment: Include HTML with a [mcve]

Comment: @MasterBob That is the whole javascript file. I am looking to get it to recognize that the score has reached 100 so I can begin to add levels further on.

Comment: @zer00ne I added the HTML

Answer (score 1):

You will be aided by having a game function that tracks the score.  Here is one way of achieving it - I have left out the animation stuff because it makes it clearer to read without.

```js
function createGame(onScoreChanged, onLevelChanged) {
    let score = 0;
    const scoreIncrement = 10;
    let level = 1;

    const incrementScore = () => {
        score += scoreIncrement;
        onScoreChanged(score);
        if (score >= (level * 100)) {
            onLevelChanged(++level);
        }
    }
    
    return {
        incrementScore
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // these functions are used to respond when score/level changes
    const scoreSubscriber = function(newScore) {
        $('#score').html('Score: ' + newScore);
    }

    const levelSubscriber = function(newLevel) {
        alert('You reached level ' + newLevel);
    }

    // initialise game
    const game = createGame(scoreSubscriber, levelSubscriber);

    // add the click handler
    $('#cursor').click(function () {
        game.incrementScore();
        // do animation stuff
    })

    // start your animations
});
```

```css
#cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="score">Score: </div>
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

As an aside, putting your click handler on all `img` elements is probably unwise, so I have used its id attribute instead.